# select/deselect of checkboxes not working in ie-7

Tags: jquery

i have a list of emails and checkboxes before all of them. At the bottom, i have a button "select all" that selects all the email checkboxes. Its working fine for mozilla and ie-8, but for ie-7, it is only able to select the first checkbox.

the code i am using is

```
$('#selectAllEmail').click (function () {                   
  $('#checkBoxTable tbody tr ').find(':checkbox').each(function () {
      $(this).click();
  });
});
```

where "selectAllEmail" is the id of the select/deselect all button.
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$('#selectAllEmail').click (function () {                   
  $('#checkBoxTable tbody tr ').find(':checkbox').each(function () {
      this.checked = !(this.checked);
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried, but still it doesnt work in ie-7.Only the first checkbox is getting checked, others are ignored. is there any way in which the document mode can be set to ie-8 when the page loads??coz in ie-8 it works properly.